# How to use awk to find and replace with calculation?

Tags: awk

I have several CSS files under a folder contains `0.2rem` or `0.5rem 0.6rem`, now I want them to be all divided by 2, become `0.1rem` and `0.25rem, 0.3rem`. How can I use `awk` or `sed` or `gawk` to accomplish this?

I tried the following command but have no success:

```sh
find . -name "*.css" | xargs gawk -i inplace '{gsub(/([0-9\.]+)rem/, "(\\1 * 0.5)rem"); print $0}'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`find`** + GNU **`awk`** solution:

```
find . -type f -name "*.css" -exec gawk -i inplace \
'{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
       if ($i ~ /^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+rem/) { v=$i/2; sub(/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/, "", $i); $i=v $i } 
 }1' {} \;
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried with some change: `find . -name "*.css" | xargs gawk -i inplace '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /[0-9]\.[0-9]rem/) { sub("rem", "", $i); $i = $i * 0.4"rem" } }1'`, everything works fine, just the `;` is striped on every line. For example, `padding-bottom: 2rem;` becomes `padding-bottom: 1rem` after change. Do you know why?

Comment: @ZhangBuzz, you did not mention that in your question. Anyway, see my update

Comment: I got it! The final command I use is as this: `find . -name "*.css" | xargs gawk -i inplace '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /[0-9]+\.[0-9]+rem/) { v=$i/2; sub(/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/, "", $i); $i=v $i } }1'`

Answer (score 8):

Not sure about `sed/gawk`, but here's one with `perl`

```
$ echo '0.2rem or 0.5rem 0.6rem' | perl -pe 's/\d+(\.\d+)?(?=rem)/$&*0.5/ge'
0.1rem or 0.25rem 0.3rem
```

- `\d+(\.\d+)?` match digits with optional fractional part

  - `(?=rem)` to ensure the number is followed by `rem`
- `$&*0.5` multiply the number by `0.5` - the `e` modifier allows to use Perl code instead of string in replacement section

Applying to files:

```
find . -name "*.css" -exec perl -i -pe 's/\d+(\.\d+)?(?=rem)/$&*0.5/ge' {} +
```

See also: [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice)

Comment: That link is about looping over the *output* of find (e.g. `for i in $(find…)`), not using find's internal loop (`-exec` or `-execdir`).

Comment: @Sparhawk but the answers cover that aspect... and has a quote that I like very much... `find's business is evaluating expressions -- not locating files. Yes, find certainly locates files; but that's really just a side effect.`

Comment: Ah okay, yes I see mention of that now. I didn't look so deep before. Still, I'm not sure that there's a better solution for your example code.

Answer (score 4):

With `gawk`, you could use `RS` that is treated as a regexp there and the fact that there, `RT` contains what was matched by `RS`. So:

```
find . -name '*.css' -type f -exec \
  gawk -i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk -v RS='[0-9.]*[0-9]rem' -v ORS= 'RT{$0=$0 RT/2 "rem"};1' {} +
```

**Do not use `-i inplace`** as `gawk` tries to load the `inplace` extension (as `inplace` or `inplace.awk`) from the current working directory first, where someone could have planted malware. The path of the `inplace` extension supplied with `gawk` may vary with the system, see the output of `gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}'`

Answer (score 1):

```
gawk -i inplace '
{
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if($i ~ /[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?rem/) 
            $i = $i / 2 "rem"            
    }
    print
}' file_*
```

**The 3 files content before the program execution**

The `tail -n +1 -- file_*` command shows the multiple files content at once.

```
$ tail -n +1 -- file_*

==> file_1 <==
0.2rem lorem ipsum 0.5rem
Lorem 0.2rem ipsum dolor sit amet, 0.5rem consectetur adipiscing elit magna aliqua.
Lorem ipsum 0.8rem dolor sit amet, 6rem consectetur 2rem adipiscing elit magna aliqua.
0.2rem lorem ipsum 0.5rem

==> file_2 <==
0.2rem lorem ipsum 0.5rem
Lorem 0.2rem ipsum dolor sit amet, 0.5rem consectetur adipiscing elit magna aliqua.
0.2rem lorem ipsum 0.5rem
Lorem ipsum 0.8rem dolor sit amet, 6rem consectetur 2rem adipiscing elit magna aliqua.

==> file_3 <==
0.2rem lorem ipsum 0.5rem
Lorem 0.2rem ipsum dolor sit amet, 0.5rem consectetur adipiscing elit magna aliqua.
Lorem ipsum 0.8rem dolor sit amet, 6rem consectetur 2rem adipiscing elit magna aliqua.
```

**The 3 files content after the program execution**

```
$ tail -n +1 -- file_*

==> file_1 <==
0.1rem lorem ipsum 0.25rem
Lorem 0.1rem ipsum dolor sit amet, 0.25rem consectetur adipiscing elit magna aliqua.
Lorem ipsum 0.4rem dolor sit amet, 3rem consectetur 1rem adipiscing elit magna aliqua.
0.1rem lorem ipsum 0.25rem

==> file_2 <==
0.1rem lorem ipsum 0.25rem
Lorem 0.1rem ipsum dolor sit amet, 0.25rem consectetur adipiscing elit magna aliqua.
0.1rem lorem ipsum 0.25rem
Lorem ipsum 0.4rem dolor sit amet, 3rem consectetur 1rem adipiscing elit magna aliqua.

==> file_3 <==
0.1rem lorem ipsum 0.25rem
Lorem 0.1rem ipsum dolor sit amet, 0.25rem consectetur adipiscing elit magna aliqua.
Lorem ipsum 0.4rem dolor sit amet, 3rem consectetur 1rem adipiscing elit magna aliqua.
```